# Gravity forms conditional logic with Date picker

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've been struggling with gravity forms since ever. I need a conditional logic set based on day picked. I have different options for each day in a week so basically it's more important than date itself but I also need to obtain a date from our visitors. I understand I could add 2 fields (one with days in a week and another with date picker) but that's just not good approach at all.

Is there anyway I could retrieve information based on date picked? I just need to know if Mon, Tue, etc... And of course I need to populate other fields based on that.

I thought of dynamic population but I am not sure how to do so.

Hopefully this is clear enough for a guru among you guys to help me out. A help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

This plugin provides this functionality:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-conditional-logic-dates/